# PHP signup form validation

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have this simple form on submit it will be redirected to `submit.php`, if there are errors it shows error messages on `submit.php`. Now what I want that the error messages will be shown back to form page.

```
<html>
<head>
<? require_once('lib.php'); ?>
</head>
<body>
<form name="my-form" id="my-form" method="post" action="submit.php">
        Your name:
        <input name="name" value="" size="30" maxlength="255" />
        Your email:
        <input name="email" value="" size="30" maxlength="255" />
        Your favourite color:
            <select name="fav_color">
                <option value="">-select please-</option>
                <option value="Black">Black</option>
                <option value="White">White</option>
                <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
                <option value="Red">Red</option>
                <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
            </select>
        Your comment:
        <textarea name="comment" rows="6" cols="35"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />         
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php

require_once('lib.php');

function getErrors($postData,$rules){

  $errors = array();

  // validate each existing input
  foreach($postData as $name => $value){

    //if rule not found, skip loop iteration
    if(!isset($rules[$name])){
        continue;       
    }

    //convert special characters to HTML entities
    $fieldName = htmlspecialchars($name);

    $rule = $rules[$name];

    //check required values
    if(isset($rule['required']) && $rule['required'] && !$value){
        $errors[] = 'Field '.$fieldName.' is required.';
    }

    //check field's minimum length
    if(isset($rule['minlength']) && strlen($value) < $rule['minlength']){
         $errors[] = $fieldName.' should be at least '.$rule['minlength'].' characters length.';    
    }

    //verify email address     
    if(isset($rule['email']) && $rule['email'] && !filter_var($value,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
      $errors[] = $fieldName.' must be valid email address.';
    }

    $rules[$name]['found'] = true;

  }


  //check for missing inputs
  foreach($rules as $name => $values){
    if(!isset($values['found']) && isset($values['required']) && $values['required']){
      $errors[] = 'Field '.htmlspecialchars($name).' is required.';
    }

  }

  return $errors;
}

$errors = getErrors($_POST,$validation_rules);

if(!count($errors)){
  echo 'Your form has no errors.';
}
else{  
  echo '<strong>Errors found in form:</strong><ul><li>';
  echo join('</li><li>',$errors);
  echo '</li></ul><p>Correct your errors and try again.</p>';
}
?>
```

As this php code display the error messages on same page. I want to display that error messages back on the `form.php page`. Does anyone help me to do so..

Answer (score 3):

[This article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) describes your solution.

You should create a validator script(for example validate.php) and submit the form there for validation. If the validation fails, validator script should return a (JSON, XML, whatever you want) array of validation errors. Else - return a redirect link.

So when you click "submit" on your form an AJAX request to validator.php should happen, not a redirect.

You should consider using a framework for such problems. It would save a lot of coding time.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to put your signup page as your form action, and wrap the php code with:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //php code here
}
```

Then you can copy the php code and paste it at the beginning of your html page. Then set your form action to your page.

If you want to hide part of the form when the PHP code is processed, you can do it like this::

```
echo '<style>.style1 {display: none }</style>";
```

*or you could even show a custom message to the user after registration in the same form:*

```
echo '<div class="highlight"><p class="textcenter"><h5>You have successfully registered for blah blah blah.</h5></p><p>Thank you!</p><style>.style1 {display: none }</style>";
```

Note that I'm assuming that the rest of your body tag is style with class `stlye1`.

This also ensures only the text needed in the html page i.e. *the visible text* is loaded when the user submits the form.

Answer (score 0):

As Sergey Eremin pointed, it is good to consider a framework for this kind of tasks.

Anyway, here is how I would do it in PHP. All the code is contained one page (submit.php). So, the form submits to itself. When the user opens submit.php the form is displayed. When they click on submit, the program checks if a name, a valid email, a favorite color and a comment are provided. If none of them has been left empty and the email is valid, the program displays "Everything is okay". Otherwise it redirects the user back to the form and points the fields that have not been filled properly. And every data that the user previously provided is passed through the redirect URL. Using $_GET it is retrieved and displayed in the form so the user does not need to retype everything from scratch.

Please do not forget to clean/escape the data before insertion in the database.

Hope this helps.

```
<?php 
    //if the form has been submitted
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

        //extract data submitted through the form and assign date to variables
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $favoriteColor = $_POST['fav_color'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];

        //pattern against which to check email validity
        $good_email = "[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";

        //if provided data is valid (email especially) and no form field has been left empty display "everything is okay" 
        if(strlen($name) > 0 && strlen($email) > 0 && preg_match("/$good_email/", $email, $regs) && strlen($favoriteColor) > 0 && strlen($comment) > 0){
            echo "Everything is okay";
        }
        //otherwise redirect the user back to the form and indicate errors that they need to correct
        else{

            //build an error message string where the user is shown where the issue is
            $error_message = "There are errors with your form."; //starting point for the error message 

            //if message has been left empty let the user know that the name is required
            if(strlen($name) == 0){
                $error_message .= "<br/>Name is required";
            }
            //if the email is left empty let the user know that an email is required 
            if(strlen($email) == 0){
                $error_message .= "<br/>Email is required";
            }
            //if the email does not match the pattern ($good_email) let the user know that the email they have supplied is invalid 
            if(!(preg_match("/$good_email/", $email, $regs))){
                $error_message .= "<br/>Email is not valid";
            }
            //if the a favorite color has not been selected let the user know that they need to select a favorite color
            if(strlen($favoriteColor) == 0){
                $error_message .= "<br/>Favorite color can not be left empty";
            }
            //if the comment is left empty let the user know that comment is required
            if(strlen($comment) == 0){
                $error_message .= "<br/>Comment is required";
            }
            //if any field is left empty or the email is invalid redirect the user back to the form along with the data they submitted 
            header("Location: submit.php?&submittedName=$name&error=$error_message&submittedEmail=$email&submittedColor=$favoriteColor&submittedComment=$comment");
        }
    }
    //if no submission display the form
    else{
?>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<?php
    //display the error message 
    //error message is passed through the url
    if (isset($_GET['error']))
    {
        echo "<p style='color:red'>".$_GET['error']."</a>";
    }
?>
<form name="my-form" id="my-form" method="post" action="submit.php">
        Your name:
        <input name="name" value="<?php if($_GET['error']) { echo $_GET['submittedName'];} //if there's been an error with form submission display the name the user prevously submitted ?>" size="30" maxlength="255" />
        Your email:
        <input name="email" value="<?php if($_GET['error']) { echo $_GET['submittedEmail'];} //if there's been an error with form submission display the email the user prevously submitted ?>" size="30" maxlength="255" />
        Your favorite color:
            <select name="fav_color">
                <option value="">-select please-</option>
                <option value="Black">Black</option>
                <option value="White">White</option>
                <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
                <option value="Red">Red</option>
                <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
            </select>
        Your comment:
        <textarea name="comment" rows="6" cols="35"><?php if($_GET['error']) { echo $_GET['submittedComment'];} //if there's been an error with form submission display the comment the user prevously submitted ?></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>         
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```